# don't retype search

Tags: search

When searching for something in vim or gvim, I use the `/`. If I make a type and press enter, I need to type the string in again, hopefully a second time without a typo.

Is it possible to configure vim to have a recently searched list so I can `<leader>`-key something? If not, how do you handle typos when searching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `q/` to open the command-line window with the previous search history. As a bonus you can use your standard vim editing maps. For more help see `:h q/`.

Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)

You can also use `/` then use the up arrow (similar to bash) to bring up the previous search.

To help with typo's consider turning on `'incsearch'` to show the current match. You can add the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
set incsearch
```

See `:h 'incsearch'` for more information.

You may also be interested in [traces.vim](https://github.com/xtal8/traces.vim) if you want highlighting for `:substitute` and ranges.

Comment: Nice, the up arrow also works with `:%s/`. I didn't know that either. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Vim already has a recently searched list. You can use the up and down arrows to cycle through your search (or command) history.